# What is different between the EV3 Home and Educational sets?

Tags: ev3, education

The newly announced LEGO Mindstorms EV3 sets for home and education have some differences, but it isn't clear to me what they are, specifically.  It seems that have different sensors, perhaps different exotic pieces (like a remote or caster wheel) and possibly slightly different software.  Granted, the sets have not been released, but, what do we know about that is different in the two sets?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both sets include an EV3 intelligent brick.

### Hardware

The Retail (Home) edition (set 31313) includes:

- 2 large motors, 1 small
- 1 touch, 1 color, 1 infrared proximity , 1 remote IR beacon

[image: EV3 Retail Hardware]

The Education set includes:

- 2 large motors, 1 small
- 2 touch, 1 color, 1 Ultrasonic with red LED, 1 Gyro
- 1 rechargeable battery (battery charger sold separately)

[image: EV3 Education Hardware]

### Software

The software for the education version is [sold separately to the core set](http://robotsquare.com/2013/11/25/difference-between-ev3-home-edition-and-education-ev3/). As well as the programming software, includes datalogging tools, and a firmware version that allows on-brick datalogging.

There is also a difference regarding sensor support: only the education version provide blocks to manage ultrasonic and gyro sensors included in that version. NXT temperature sensor and Energy meter are supported too. And of course, models being different between edu and retail versions, the building instructions that are included in the software are different.

### Robots

Each edition includes different Technic bricks and instructions for different robots. You can find a list of those robots at the [LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Comparison project](https://github.com/bittner/lego-mindstorms-ev3-comparison), and product pictures on [Robot Square](http://robotsquare.com/2013/11/25/difference-between-ev3-home-edition-and-education-ev3/).

### Parts

The [EV3 Expansion Set](https://education.lego.com/en-us/products/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-expansion-set/45560) adds many Technic bricks for even more robots and is suitable as an upgrade for both sets. However, to build all robots officially published by LEGO for either set you need to buy additional parts in any case.

The [LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Comparison project](https://github.com/bittner/lego-mindstorms-ev3-comparison) on GitHub lists all parts in a spread sheet, tells you which pieces are missing from "education + expansion" to "retail + expansion" and vice-versa, so you can find out which parts (numbers + names) to order in addition.

Comment: Do we know if the retail set comes with a castor wheel?

Comment: As far as I know, the castor wheel is just a component made up of small Technic pieces. The main part you would need is the actual small wheel, which I do not think is included in the retail set. It's hard to know at this point in time; we will have to wait until the parts list is published

Comment: I think the caster is the right-most piece in the diagram of the educational set.  Building casters for the NXT was a real pain, so I'm hoping that both sets include it!

Comment: I've made this post into a community wiki. Please feel free to update with new information

Answer (score 3):

### Hardware

| No |  | Education EV3 | home EV3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Intelligent Brick | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Large Motor | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Middle Motor | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Ultrasonic Sensor | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | Touch Sensor | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | Color Sensor | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | Gyro Sensor | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | Infrared Sensor | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | IR Beacon (Infrared Remote Control) | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | Rechargeable DC Battery | 1 | 0 |
| 11 | Transformer 10V DC | Option | 0 |
| 12 | the number of parts | 541 parts | 550 parts |
| 13 | tray | ○ | × |

### Software

| No |  | Education EV3 | home EV3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lobby（the main menu of the software） | ○ | △ |
| 2 | Programming | ○ | ○ |
| 3 | Data Logging | ○ | × |
| 4 | Contents Editor | ○ | × |
| 5 | Robot Educator | ○ | △（assembly diagrams for 5 models） |
| 6 | Sound Editor | ○ | ○ |
| 7 | Image Editor | ○ | ○ |

Based on this comparison:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140227052442/http://www.ev-3.net/en/archives/98

Some other direct links:

- [LEGO Mindstorms Education EV3 Core Set brick list](http://cache.lego.com/r/education/-/media/LEGO%20Education/Home/Downloads/Marketing%20Tools/Global/MINDSTORMS%20EV3/ts.20130109T120820.45544%20Core%20Set%20product%20sheet.pdf) - from Lego site
- [LEGO Mindstorms Education EV3 expansion Set brick list](https://c10645061.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/resources/45560mindstormstopcardback.pdf)
- [Lego Mindstorms RETAIL](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/08/review-lego-mindstorms-ev3-means-giant-robots-powerful-computers/) - article

Brickset (check Parts tab):

- [31313 - EV3 retail](http://brickset.com/sets/31313-1/Mindstorms-EV3)
- [45544 - Education EV3 Core Set](http://brickset.com/sets/45544-1/Education-EV3-Core-Set)
- [45560 - Education EV3 Expansion Set](http://brickset.com/sets/45560-1/Education-EV3-Expansion-Set)

Comment: Main link of this answer now unfortunately dangling (404).

Comment: @Peterino - the link is now fixed.

Comment: The web.archive.org link goes to a blank page for me.

Comment: @chicks I just checked and the link is working for me. Webarchive needs some time to retrieve old page from archive - please be patient and in case of timeout - retry.

Comment: It is working for me now.  :)

Answer (score 3):

There are [differences between EV3 Education and Home set](http://www.intorobotics.com/8-major-differences-between-mindstorms-ev3-education-and-home-edition/) including software, hardware and parts.

## Software

A slight difference is in the firmware that comes with on-board datalogging capabilities only for Education version

## Hardware

The retail version includes a small amount of components compared with educational set, components that include one small motor, 2 large motors, and four sensors (touch, color, infrared proximity, and remote IR beacon).
The educational set includes the castor wheel, 1 small motor, 2 large motors, 2 touch, 1 color and 1 ultrasonic sensor with red LED, 1 gyro, 1 rechargeable battery, and the possibility to download the EV3 software.

## Parts

There is a difference of overall 10 elements between retail and educational versions

Comment: There are more than 10 elements different between the two versions. A complete list of pieces comparing the two editions and the expansion set can be found in the [lego-mindstorms-ev3-comparison project](https://github.com/bittner/lego-mindstorms-ev3-comparison) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I received my EV3 educational kit last week.  Yes, it comes with the a rechargeable battery, battery charger, the castor wheel, and a code that permits me to download the EV3 software.  It is disappointing that the educational kit does NOT come with the infra red sensor or IR remote.  Also the educational set comes with approximately 500 more technic bricks than the retail version.

Comment: My education core set did not contain a charger or a software download link. If you have a link to download the software, can you help send it to me or post. Thanks

Comment: I am planning to buy one for myself( age: 25+) , I am gonna buy it for first time and education set looks more appealing to me ( Gyro, 2 touch and more parts). Please suggest which one I should buy then

Comment: Edu set comes with *fewer* technic pieces (not "500 more") than the retail version.