# No software with the EV3 robot?

Tags: software, ev3

We bought EV3 robot but it looks like there is no software and we have to pay an additional $99 for the EV3 software. Is this true?

Answer (score 8):

For the retail version, the link is: https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads and for the education version, the link is: https://education.lego.com/en-us/educationdownloads/freeproductspage

Comment: If you later buy a retail kit, however, you should be able to use the software which comes with it to control both kits.

Comment: ...but retail version - as of this writing - has not blocks to use ultrasonic or gyro sensors that come with EDU version.

Comment: You may also want to check [What is different between the EV3 Home and Educational sets?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1819/99) (Philo, since what you just said isn't mentionned in that particular Q/A, you may want to go there as well and add what you know)

Comment: You may now download and add gyro and ultrasonic sensors blocks for retail software. See eg. http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/ev3-blocks/gyro/

Answer (score 5):

The EV3 software (for home use) is available on: http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/ddsoftwaredownload/

Answer (score 3):

The home edition software will be a free download available from LEGO's website as of September 1st. It will include programming for the ultrasonic and gyro sensors and will be compatible withe the education version of the EV3 brick.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-MINDSTORMS-EV3-31313

Answer (score 1):

The [retail edition of the NXT kit](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=31313-1) doesn't include software in the box, and provides only limited printed building instructions (presumably to save on costs).

However, as indicated on the box, you can to download it from [LEGO.com/mindstorms](http://LEGO.com/mindstorms) directly, and for free.

Currently, the software is on the [download](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/ddsoftwaredownload/) page.

The instructions can be found on the [products](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/products/ev3/31313/) page, under "EV3 Starter Robots" and "EV3 Bonus Robots". You can download them as PDF or view them interactively online. You can also install a [mobile application](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/funzone/mobile-apps/3d-builder/) to view them easily while building.