# EV3 Education Edition software license

Tags: ev3, software, education

I got a new EV3 education kit.

Can I install it on a several computers or does the license work on one computer only?

Comment: I've got a similar question. I think it can be merged with the main question.
If I have single user license: 1. Can I reinstall EV3 software on the same computer after OS reinstall? 2. Can I install EV3 software on another computer if I uninstall EV3 from the first one?

Answer (score 4):

That depends on which version of the Education Software you purchased:

- [LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Education EV3 Software Single User](http://shop.legoeducation.com/gb/product/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-single-user-2000045-200/)
  As the name implies, this is only allowed to be installed on a single computer: "The single license version of the EV3 Software allows you to install and run the software on one computer."
- [LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Education EV3 Software Site Licence](http://shop.legoeducation.com/gb/product/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-site-licence-2000046-201/)
  This version allows you to install the software on a number of computers within a single location: "The site license version of the EV3 Software is necessary when installing on more than one computer. It allows you to install and run the software on all computers located at the address of the purchasing institution."

If you're planning on installing this on more than three computers the Site License is the way to go.

Note that the Home Edition is a [separate download](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/ddsoftwaredownload/), and would have it's own licensing, but appears to be freely available, and installable on as many computers as you like - [details of some of the differences can be found in this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1820/56) to "What is different between the EV3 Home and Educational sets?".

---

In response to Alex's comment:

Without seeing the full wording of the license, it's hard to advise you correctly, however:

1. Usually you can reinstall software on the same computer after an OS reinstall - depending on the validation mechanism you may need to contact Customer Services to get it reset, but I doubt this will be the case with this.
2. Again, this is typically supported by most software licenses - it's often things like transferring ownership that are expressly excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased the education set through First Lego League, you are allowed to install on up to 10 computers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the license agreement supplied with the software (using the activation code from the Software Single License) you may:

a. use the Software on one single computer;

b. use the Software on a second computer as long as the first and
        second computers are not used simultaneously;

c. copy the Software for back-up and archival purposes, provided any
        copy made must contain all of the original Software’s proprietary
        notices;

...

So: You may install on more than 1 computer, but not use the software on more than 1 computer simultaneously.

You can reinstall the software after OS re-installation, as long as you have a backup copy of the software. According to the licence document (with the activation code), you can download the software only once. This seems not to be the case at the moment, but might change in the future.

You can install on a second computer, without removing it from the first. You are not allowed to use it on both computers at the same time, however.