# Price of EV3 education software

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, software, education

After looking around on the Lego Education website, I failed to find the price of the education software.  I currently have the retail version of the software, but I want the extra features and blocks in the education version.  Does anyone know how much the education EV3 software is?

Answer (score 2):

The [LEGO Education website](https://education.lego.com/en-us/lego-education-product-database/mindstorms-ev3/2000045-lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-single-user) does indeed not list prices, as you have to go through a distributor and get a quote there.

However, it seems that LEGO acts as its own distributor in the United States, which is slightly confusing, especially considering it's on a separate website: [http://www.legoeducation.us/](http://www.legoeducation.us/eng/product/ev3_software/2577). There you can get prices, and you'll see a single-user license costs 99.95$ and a site license is 399.95$ (not sure how many installations that covers, though). Of course, outside of the United States you have to [find a local distributor](https://education.lego.com/en-us/distributors) and request a quote.

Comment: The UK store (with prices) can be found here: http://shop.legoeducation.com/gb/category/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-22/ - I believe it also covers Germany. As these are not really "retail" the prices for the UK are listed both including and excluding tax. As per [my answer on licenses](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2510/56), the site license covers all computers at a single location.