# Should I buy the retail or education version of Mindstroms EV3?

Tags: ev3, education

There are other questions that list the differences in the retail and educational version but I cannot judge which one I should buy (educational or retail).

I am buying Mindstorms for the first time, The educational kit looks more appealing to me as it has more parts, gyro sensor (I need this) and it is also $10 less than the retail version.

I am 27 year old and want to buy the best value for money and one I can get most out it. Any add-on suggestion will be also great as it is not available in my country and I would like to buy most of the stuff in one go.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the Education version doesn't come with any software - if you want to use the full features of the Education EV3 brick (mostly around Data Logging), you will need to purchase the Education version of the software - thus making the price about £70-85 higher (which may still be cheaper than purchasing the Retail edition and [adding the extra components](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1820/56)).

Answer (score 2):

Edu version is better. You can use Home software with it and it has more and better sensors (2 touch instead of 1 and ultrasound instead of infrared). It has better mechanical parts - better tracks and metal ball to use as third wheel.

It is also cheaper for some reason.

Comment: I believe it's cheaper because originally to use all the sensors you had to purchase the Education version of the software as well... I believe the more recent updates to the home software now support the additional sensors in the kit, so it's just the data logging you're missing out on.