# Where can I download the EV3 education edition software for free?

Tags: ev3, software, education

I have a site license but I'm not able to find the download for the software anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's strange how this guy asks a question and then never comes back to check for three years. But FYI, you should see the download somewhere here: https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software

Answer (score 4):

According to an [education Community Manager](https://community.education.lego.com/t5/LEGO-MINDSTORMS-Education-EV3/Where-i-can-download-EV3-education-version-soft/m-p/857#M14) you should have received a link when you purchased the licence.

If you didn't receive one you should contact your reseller - it depends on which region you are in as to whether logging in to the LEGO education site would enable a direct link for you.

Answer (score 3):

https://education.lego.com/en-us/support

You have to be logged in with your credentials, then click the download button.

Comment: As of January 1, 2016 you no longer have to have an activation key to download the software. Source: https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/578017979013099/

Answer (score 3):

The software for the LEGO Education version of the EV3 needs a license (either a single license or a site license). AFAIK, all EV3 Education purchases come with a Software License, which also includes instructions on where to download the software.

There is nothing preventing you from using the retail (non-Education) version of the software though, which is a free download from http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software. It might prompt you to update the firmware on your EV3 to the "Home" version (currently v1.09H) but you can always switch back to the "Education" version (currently v1.09E).

Comment: Yep, looks like they've changed the sales model [since this was last asked](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2526/56) - as the UK Education shop now offers sets with Software, as either a "1 set" or in multiples for 2, 8, 16 or 30 pupils - there doesn't seem to be distinction between single or site licenses any more - possibly due to the tablet based tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this link and choose the software you want 
http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/ddsoftwaredownload/

Comment: Hi Calin - that's the "home edition" unfortunately, which doesn't have the data logging and other capabilities of the Education edition.

Answer (score 1):

If not yet had a license: Try download at this site but it will cost you RM2120 (if you're rich)...: http://lego.sasbadi.com/product-details.php?id=46&type=robotics&iframe=true&width=900&height=510

If already bought: Just follow the link at the license and enter the codes!(might need to make an account for the web)

Comment: Is it an official reseller?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Education Edition for the LEGO Mindstorms EV3 [here](https://education.lego.com/en-us) (footer of the page). It is available for free.

You only need a valid LEGO ID for a login. If you haven't a LEGO ID you can create one on the linked page.